# Why would I prefer qCDebug over qDebug?

Tags: qt

In Qt we can use the qDebug - and similar - macros for logging purposes. To organize the output we can define and use QLoggingCategories, together with the qCDebug macro.

The [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qloggingcategory.html#qCDebug) tells us:

> The macro expands to code that checks whether QLoggingCategory::isDebugEnabled() evaluates to true. If so, the stream arguments are processed and sent to the message handle

We do so by using the category using the `Q_LOGGING_CATEGORY`. Consider the following minimal example:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QLoggingCategory>

Q_LOGGING_CATEGORY(cat, "cat")

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    qCDebug(cat) << "Hello World!";

    return a.exec();
}
```

I noticed, that I can omit the `C`, providing me with the following line:
`qDebug(cat) << "Hello World!";`.

When executed, both lines give the same output:

> cat: Hello World

I can also set `QT_LOGGING_RULES` to `cat=false` to turn of the message - in both variants.
Why would I use qCDebug over qDebug if the result is effectively the same?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the code for both Macros shows the differences:

qDebug():

```
#define qDebug QMessageLogger(QT_MESSAGELOG_FILE, QT_MESSAGELOG_LINE, QT_MESSAGELOG_FUNC).debug
```

qCDebug():

```
#  define qCDebug(category, ...) \
for (bool qt_category_enabled = category().isDebugEnabled(); qt_category_enabled; qt_category_enabled = false) \
    QMessageLogger(QT_MESSAGELOG_FILE, QT_MESSAGELOG_LINE, QT_MESSAGELOG_FUNC, category().categoryName()).debug(__VA_ARGS__)
```

So the main difference is, that `qCDebug(cat)` will check wether the category is enabled, *before* creating a QMessageLogger instance. If we use the `qDebug()` macro, an overloaded function with a QLoggingCategory argument exists, I suppose for convenience? This function [will perform the check](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/corelib/global/qlogging.cpp.html#469) only after the QMessageLogger was created.

I setup a simple benchmark to see the performance difference this makes - code below. Keeping the message length the same for all tests, I had the following results (numbers in brackets show the number of iterations, value is average time per iteration in msec):

```
+----------+---------------+-------------------+--------+
| category |    qDebug     |      qCDebug      | Factor |
+----------+---------------+-------------------+--------+
| enabled  | 0.031(2048)   | 0.024(4096)       |   1.29 |
| disabled | 0.00077(4096) | 0.000016(4194304) |   48.0 |
+----------+---------------+-------------------+--------+
```

Exact numbers varied, of course, but the overall image stayed the same. If debug output for the category is enabled, both macros perform more or less the same, while if the category is disabled, using `qCDebug` will be about ten to a hundred times faster than `qDebug`. So the verdict should be to always use qCDebug when working with categories, as the documentation suggests, though the difference will probably only be noticeable if you produce a *lot* of (disabled) output.

Test Code for verification below:

---

```
Q_LOGGING_CATEGORY(test, "test")


class DebugBM: public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

private slots:
    void xdebugEnabled()
    {
        QBENCHMARK {
            qDebug(test) << "Test.";
        }
    }

    void cDebugEnabled()
    {
        QBENCHMARK {
            qCDebug(test) << "Test.";
        }
    }

    void xdebugDisable()
    {
        QLoggingCategory::setFilterRules("test.debug=false");
        QBENCHMARK {
            qDebug(test) << "Test.";
        }
    }

    void cDebugDisable()
    {
        QLoggingCategory::setFilterRules("test.debug=false");
        QBENCHMARK {
            qCDebug(test) << "Test.";
        }
    }
};
QTEST_MAIN(DebugBM)
#include "DebugBM.moc"
```

Comment: I am trying to debug one Qt application I got and I have bunch of qCInfo and qCDebug calls in code. Where can the messages be seen?

Comment: @rkj If you didn't change something, debug will be sent to std::out of the application, which in most cases is the console, the application is run from. If you run a graphical application and have no console / it's not displayed, you can first try to run it from a console (i.e. cmd or powershell on windows) or alternatively have a look at [qInstallMessageHandler](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6.5/qtlogging.html#qInstallMessageHandler) and set a function there, that redirects all log messages to a file you can look at.